# Drupal7 how to do form validation using entity registration form using

Tags: drupal-7

I am using entity registrations to let users register to an event. I have some fields that I want to validate depending on the value of other fields.

So, using hook_form_id_form_alter, i was able to add a second validation function. The second function is where i hoped I can add the code for validating the registration form.

```
function coastal_custom_form_registration_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'event_registration_form_validate';  
}
```

But whenever I submit the form, the function that is supposed to do the validation never gets called.

```
//this function never gets called
function event_registration_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state){
  drupal_set_message('hi from validation');
  form_set_error('you are in form_registration');

}
```

I have been figuring how to do this for the whole day. Have anyone figured out how this is done? Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of your module? Did you remember to clear your cache?

Comment: Yes i cleared the cache. The module is a custom module named coastal_custom. This module works because there are other hooks in it as well and they arw working fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Entity Registration module but check to make sure that the `FORM_ID` you have of `form_registration` is correct.

Comment: with a clean drupal 7 install, and with only 2 contrib modules installed (entity api and entity registration), the above validation code works. But when tested in my development drupal install with more than 50 contrib modules, the validation code does not work. So there must be a conflict somewhere.

Comment: I found out that you need to call by reference $form. So the proper way of stating the function is  

`function coastal_custom_form_registration_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {`  

instead of  

`function coastal_custom_form_registration_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {`

Comment: Good catch.  You can post an answer to your own question and accept it so that the community knows this issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the api documentation on hook_form_alter, I found out that you have to pass by reference $form. So the correct way of writing the function should be:

```
function coastal_custom_form_registration_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'event_registration_form_validate';  
}
```

Take note that there is an ampersand (&) before the $form variable.